# GPS prediction of position

Tags: gps, prediction

I am using IMU with frequency 50Hz and GPS with frequency 4Hz, therefore, for every 12-13 points of IMU I get the same measurement from GPS. Is there some way to predict the GPS position for points 2-11? I do not have other data, just the position data from GPS.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried Kalman filter, but that needs another input, in terms of velocity or acceleration (and I have none). Then I tried interpolation, but that is not very plausible.